# json for loop and place it in UIPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, uipickerview

It turns out that I'm working with json and have a label "quantity" would like to make a cycle that loops through me the amount of that label and I show it in a pickerView. Here is my code. thank you very much.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @John,

Your question is quite vague and I apparently don't understand your objective. Can you please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: Do not post images of your code. Copy and paste the actual text into your question (and be sure to format it properly).

Comment: Hi Ruchira, not really as more explain my idea, what I want is to make a cycle that loops through me of what comes from json ie an amount and the cycle scroll me that much and I show it in uipikerView. My idea is selecionar three articles and the cycle shows Me me UIPickerView 1.2 and 3 etc.

Comment: Please post actual code instead of screenshots. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**what I want is to cycle the value "quantity" and show me the values according to the amount to be placed in an array and then in UIPickerView example:
number = 5
arrayCantidad = 1,2,3,4,5

Thank you**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.labelEstilo.text= [self.detailRetro objectForKey:@"estilo"];
self.labelColor.text= [self.detailRetro objectForKey:@"color"];
self.labelPrecio.text=[self.detailRetro objectForKey:@"precio"];
cantTextField.text=[self.detailRetro objectForKey:@"cantidad"];
objeto=[self.detailRetro objectForKey:@"cantidad"];

 _arrayPicker =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:objeto, nil];

[_arrayPicker addObject:objeto];





self.title =self.labelEstilo.text;

picker.delegate=self;
picker.dataSource=self;
cantTextField.delegate=self;
}
```